# Hooking Win32 windows creation/resize/querying sizes

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to "stretch" an existing application.

**The goal** is to make an existing application become larger without changing the code of that application.
**A cosntraint** is that the stretched application will not "notice" it, so if the application query a created window size it'll see the original size and not the resized size.

I managed to resize the windows using *`SetWindowsHookEx`*:

```
HHOOK hMessHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,CBTProc, hInst, 0);
```

And:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc( __in  int nCode,
                          __in  WPARAM wParam, 
                          __in  LPARAM lParam)
{
   if (HCBT_CREATEWND == nCode)
   {
      CBT_CREATEWND *WndData = (CBT_CREATEWND*) lParam;
      // Calculate newWidth and newHeight values...
      WndData->lpcs->cx = newWidth;
      WndData->lpcs->cy = newHeight;
   }

   CallNextHookEx(hMessHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to the make the stretched application see the original sizes.

For example, if a .NET form is created:

```
public class SimpleForm : Form
{
    public SimpleForm()
    {
        Width = 100;
        Height = 200;
    }
}
```

And later the size is queried:

```
void QuerySize(SimpleForm form)
{
   int width = form.Width;
   int height = form.Height;
}
```

I'd like *`width`* and *`height`* be `100` and `200` and not the resized values. I was unable to find the right hook which queries the size of an existing window.

What is the right way to hook window size querying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, queries for window size aren't handled by messages -- they are direct API calls such as [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- so they can't be intercepted by standard Windows hooks. You might want to look into the [Detours API](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), which allows you to hook arbitrary Win32 functions. (You can find a tutorial on Detours [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/funapihook.aspx))