# Listening to another window's resize event

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I try to listen to an another window's event. I always want to set the Window mode to full screen if someone try to change the window size.

After some research about this topic, I've found some information about Event hooks. Now I'm trying to get this to work, but there is no example for listening to window events.

Currently I try to use `SetWinEventHook`, but it seems like this is not working with window events.

Can someone give me a tip how to do that? If I find a solution, I will post the answer.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Hello. If I remember correctly,You cannot directly hook the creation/sizing/positioning of a window, as it works with mouse and keyboard. You might want to look into a nice example, on how to hook properly, in this link (only to get the basic idea behind hooking. It is not VB so You might want to translate it by Yourself somehow).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs
Also check this post,where a relatively similar question was asked. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204717/hooking-win32-windows-creation-resize-querying-sizes
The introduced toolset is called detours.

Comment: @icbytes: What do you propose [EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE and EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) report then?

Comment: I could answer this, if I ever had played with detours or used the constants, which You ask for. Unfortunately I cannot tell You, which one to use. I just intensified "googling" for some helpful hints for the OP.

Comment: Can you define what is `another window` for you? Is this a different process or it is different window in your assembly?

Comment: @icbytes: How can you have not used `SetWinEventHook`, and then blatantly lie to us by saying *"If I remember correctly"*?

Comment: I was reading some times about this, but never really started this kind of hooking. I hooked some stuff some years ago, but never this kind of events. Last time I was searching for some stuff regarding the hooking of metro-applications, I think, I also stumbled over such stuff in that time.Nevertheless, I did not write, what I usually wanted to.

Comment: @T.S. It's a different process.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? You can get the resize event from the second form like this.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents Form As Form2


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form = New Form2

    form.Show()

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form.Resize
    Dim size As Size = CType(sender, Form2).Size

    Console.WriteLine("Window Resize: " + size.ToString)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but that's not what I want, I need it for an external process. I'm sure that I need to use SetWinEventHook, but I don't know how.